# Is $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}- \{0\}$ a second-countable space?

Tags: general-topology

Is $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}- \{0\}$ a second-countable space? It is certainly true for $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ since the product of open intervals $(a_{1},b_{1}) \times \cdots \times (a_{n+1},b_{n+1}), \text{  } a_{i},b_{i} \in \mathbb{Q}$ gives a countable basis. How does one construct a countable basis with regard to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}- \{0\}$?

Comment: Take out all the basis elements of $\mathbb R^{n+1} $ containing the origin.

Comment: Any subspace of a second countable space is (in the subspace topology) second countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ consider the open balls $$B((a,b),r)$$ with $r\in\mathbb{Q},r>0$ and $r<\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$ Thus we have a countable basis.